# MVC5 Attribute Routing with file extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

Basically I am trying to use the new MVC5 routing attribute to redirect /sitemap.xml to a method as I need to dynamically create it.

```
// GET: /sitemap.xml
[Route("sitemap.xml")]
public ActionResult SiteMap()
{
    // Stuff
}
```

At the moment that doesn't work so is it possible to do it like this or will I have to use the routing table like I did before?

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Site Map",
   url: "sitemap.xml",
   defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "SiteMap" });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886093/routing-a-url-with-extension-in-mvc4-wont-work-tries-to-serve-up-static-file

Comment: I've already got that added

Comment: Well I've used that before with the correct result. You could try that runAllManagedHandlers flag to troubleshoot. If that doesn't work then something's weird somewhere.

Comment: I don't suppose you have a route prefix at the controller level so it's not /sitemap.xml but /abcd/sitemap.xml ?

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your web.config:

```xml
 <system.webServer>
 <handlers>
      <add name="ManagedDllExtension" path="*.xml" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```